# How do I implement a global keyboard hook using GTk2 C# Visual Studio on mac?

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, keyboard

This is not a duplicate question. I have read lots of implementations of low level / global keyboard hooks using C# but none of them have yet provided a solution for MacOSX Visual Studio. Basically, I have a GTK2 .net MAC application. I want (the application) to detect whenever the space key is pressed, whether the application is on focus or not. I have successfully implemented a simple keyboard hook on a console app using C# (for Mac) but my console application would not detect the global keyboard events when the application is not in focus. Even when my current application is not in focus, I want it to detect it whenever the space key is pressed. How do I do this ? Here is my **MainWindow.cs**

```
using System;
using Gtk;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;

public partial class MainWindow : Gtk.Window
 {
// MySQL to fetch visitors number
//Create a MySQL connection




int visitors = 0;





public MainWindow() : base(Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
{
    Build();
}

protected void OnDeleteEvent(object sender, DeleteEventArgs a)
{
    Application.Quit();
    a.RetVal = true;
}


public void DetectWhenSpaceKeyIsPressed(){
   if(//space key is pressed -low level keyboard hook mac OSX){

         //I send the data 

      }


 }








}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented this function for a console app for .net core in MacOS

```
if (!Console.KeyAvailable) return null;
ConsoleKeyInfo c = Console.ReadKey(true);
switch (c.Key)
{
   case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
      //go up
      break;
   case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
      //go down
      break;
   ... etc
}
```